# Xbox One S controller (via Bluetooth to Linux) isn't binding Start or Select in Nestopia

Tags: controllers, emulation, nes

I'm trying to use the emulator Nestopia with my Bluetooth Xbox One S controller. I'm able to use the controller completely fine in other games and emulators, but for whatever reason when I'm binding the buttons for Nestopia, it doesn't detect that I'm pressing Start or Select. Every other button binds just fine. This is a problem because most NES games require you to press Start to actually start the game. Any help is appreciated.

I'm on Ubuntu by the way (xfce).

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I found a fix that I can't believe I didn't think of before. Obviously, the NES controllers didn't have shoulder buttons or triggers, so just set those to Start and Select. Not the most ideal as my thumbs are trained to move to the center of the controller for them, but it's a fix I'm happy to stick with.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you figured out a workaround.

I don't know exactly where the issue is but this is probably related to the Xbox One S gamepad getting a firmware update a few years ago. The update changed the way buttons are communicated over Bluetooth (but not USB) and means that any third-party libraries that were designed to handle the old firmware need to be updated to also handle the new firmware.

My guess is that your version of Nestopia is using an older version of SDL that was released before the new firmware was added. SDL is a popular cross-platform library that does gamepad input along with a bunch of other stuff relevant for games and emulators. You could try downloading a newer version of Nestopia, which may have been compiled with a newer build of SDL.

Plugging in your gamepad over USB should also let you use those buttons normally.